# jquery - toggle between divs with default option

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am trying to toggle between divs.
It works until I want to uncheck selected element, which should show default element (option-0).

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/klawisz/fZemQ/6/

Answer (score 3):

check this out quite simple

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
        var self = $(this);   
        $('.options').hide();   
        if(self.hasClass('active') ) {
            self.removeClass('active');
            $('.options.option-0').show();
        }else{
            $('.checkbox').removeClass('active');
            self.addClass('active');
            $('.options.'+ self.attr('id')).show();
        }
});
```

fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/fZemQ/10/

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
if( $('.checkbox').hasClass('active') ) {
  $('.checkbox').removeClass('active');
}
```

You're removing the class 'active' so your if statement will always run the `else`

I've changed you code so it now works:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuwb7/

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('.options.option-0').show();
```

To

```
$('div').hasClass("option-0").show();
```

Your initial selector is looking for elements with a class of options, that contain an element with a class of option-0.